# How can centre image on face?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

I want detect face from image and centre it. How can i do ?
I have one picture like this :[image]

and i want display just face, like in this photo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a bit beyond the scope of a single question, however unless you're going to write your own face detection algo yourself, I'd suggest Apple's native class [CIDetector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CIDetector)

Example code:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];                    // 1

NSDictionary *opts = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };      // 2

CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace

                                          context:context

                                          options:opts];                    // 3



opts = @{ CIDetectorImageOrientation :

          [[myImage properties] valueForKey:kCGImagePropertyOrientation] }; // 4

NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:myImage options:opts];        // 5
```

1    Creates a context; in this example, a context for iOS. You can use any of the context-creation functions described in Processing Images.) You also have the option of supplying nil instead of a context when you create the detector.)

2    Creates an options dictionary to specify accuracy for the detector. You can specify low or high accuracy. Low accuracy (CIDetectorAccuracyLow) is fast; high accuracy, shown in this example, is thorough but slower.

3    Creates a detector for faces. The only type of detector you can create is one for human faces.

4    Sets up an options dictionary for finding faces. It’s important to let Core Image know the image orientation so the detector knows where it can find upright faces. Most of the time you’ll read the image orientation from the image itself, and then provide that value to the options dictionary.

5    Uses the detector to find features in an image. The image you provide must be a CIImage object. Core Image returns an array of CIFeature objects, each of which represents a face in the image.

Face features include:

```
left and right eye positions

mouth position

tracking ID and tracking frame count which Core Image uses to follow a face in a video segment
```

After you get an array of face features from a CIDetector object, you can loop through the array to examine the bounds of each face and each feature in the faces

```
for (CIFaceFeature *f in features)

{

    NSLog(NSStringFromRect(f.bounds));



    if (f.hasLeftEyePosition)

        NSLog("Left eye %g %g", f.leftEyePosition.x. f.leftEyePosition.y);



    if (f.hasRightEyePosition)

        NSLog("Right eye %g %g", f.rightEyePosition.x. f.rightEyePosition.y);



    if (f.hasmouthPosition)

        NSLog("Mouth %g %g", f.mouthPosition.x. f.mouthPosition.y);

}
```

When you've detected the face you can use the standard UIKit/CoreImage classes to zoom and centre.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UiImage' declares the selector 'properties'

Comment: @GabyFitcal  CIImage Class

Comment: use of undeclared identifier 'kCGImagePropertyOrientation'

Comment: You might get a better response, if you accepted posted answers. In addition to this posting compilation errors in such a curt fashion, without context, and expecting people to help you is not good form.

Comment: I just copy your code, i create this CIImage : ' CIImage *ciImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.picture objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]].CIImage;' 
after i complete this line of code: 'opts = @{ CIDetectorImageOrientation :
                      
                      [[ciImage properties] valueForKey:kCGImagePropertyOrientation] };' and i get this error